# mysql access denied for user 'odbc'@'localhost' to database

Tags: mysql, root

I installed MySql5.5 and set password during installation but when I try to use mysql from windows command prompt, I have get the error:

```
access denied for user 'odbc'@'localhost' to database password = 'YES'
```

I would like to change it back into "root@localhost" as well as to reset the password but I can't log in mysql.

How do I login to mysql with root?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to use the mysql interactive shell? You can specify usernames at the command line:

```
c:\> mysql -u root -p
```

where

```
-u = specify username
-p = prompt for password
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by implementing a little hacky solution. Downloaded hxd (hex editor) and searched for 'ODBC' (there should only be one match) and just changed it to 'root'.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging into mysql with a default no-rights user, you have to login as root if you want to do everything:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p
Enter Password: *****
```

If you never specified a root password it should be blank, if you did, you have to remember what it was, or find out how to reset the root password.